# Can I move only a few accounts to google apps paid plan?

Tags: google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

Is it possible to move a few free google accounts using a custom email (eg non gmail) to a paid google app plan whilst leaving all other accounts and emails as they are.

Here’s my scenario

I’ve got a custom domain which I run on my hosting with about 25 email accounts, about 10 of those have free google account accounts about 5 of those accounts are used regularly, for google drive and calendar etc..

I want to get the paid admin features of google apps for business for those 5 google accounts, but I don’t won’t to move my email, update mx servers, or move any of the other users to the paid google apps their.

Answer (score 0):

The best is that you contact G Suite sales and ask them.

Anyway, it isn't possible because the upgrade is made on an organization basis not on accounts basis.

Answer (score 0):

All users will need to be licensed when upgrading. You would need to upgrade all users on that domain and then migrate data from the accounts not being used into any of those other 5 or potentially move Gmail data into Groups.